# Level Sets of Continuous Function "Homotopic"

Tags: general-topology

Let $D$ be a topological space. Let $f \colon D \rightarrow [0,1]$ (where the interval $[0,1]$ on the right may be any other compact set) be continuous.

My question is now: Suppose, that the set of zeros of $f$ has some property, e.g. it contains a certain knot which is not contractible. How can I formalize that the level sets of $f$ inherit some of the properties that I have for the zero level set? (Or is this impossible?)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If $D$ is perfectly normal (e.g. $D$ is metrizable), then regardless of what $f^{-1}(0)$ is, $f^{-1}(1)$ can be absolutely any closed set. So, it is unlikely you can say anything about all level sets based on a single level set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "nice" cases, e.g. if $f$ is a smooth function on a compact manifold $D$, the Implicit Function Theorem tells you that the topology of $f^{-1}(s)$ changes only when you hit a critical value.  But in the absence of any differentiable structure, I doubt that you can say much.